# Why jack is not working when RE-plugged?

Tags: windows

On my laptop under windows 10, when I plug my earphones for the 1st time it works fine.
When I unplug the jack, sound comes back through built-in speakers, still normal.
But when I re-plug the jack, I get no audio. Both plugged earphones and built-in speakers remain silents.

If I reboot I can have sound back through plugged earphones.

Restarting `AudioSrv` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a driver/manager issue. I found out by running the windows troubleshoot tool and reinstalling drivers.
Now I have the `Realtek HD Audio Manager` appearing in notification area and handling plug/unplug events smoothly.

I did have the Realtek driver before but maybe outdated, I did not have the Realtek manager running though.